# Cannot open database version 661. Upgrade the database to the latest version

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our production database can't keep up with the reports so our DBA had set up a mirroring solution to run reports from, but it was incomplete before he left.

I have a primary and a mirror database. The primary is running SQL Server 2008 R2 and the mirror is running SQL Server 2016.

I'm trying to create a snapshot of the mirror of the SQL Server 2008 R2 source, and getting the error in the title:

> Cannot open database version 661. Upgrade the database to the latest version.

Here's my script:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase_05162017 ON
(
NAME = 'MyDatabase_Data.mdf'
, FILENAME = 'L:\mssql\userdata\MyDatabase_Data_05162017.ss'
)
AS SNAPSHOT OF MyDatabase
GO
```

I've found plenty of articles for the opposite situation where there's no downgrade path. But I'm not finding any answers for my current situation. Is there a way to set compatibility before creating the database? Is it even possible to restore snapshots of a SQL Server 2008 R2 mirror to a SQL Server 2016 database? I'm trying to do this without upgrading our production database.

Answer (score 0):

What is the compatibility level of the database running on 2008R2?  2016 requires it to be at least 2008.

Comment: Is this an **answer**? It seems more like a comment, and should be left as such.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I considered leaving it as a comment, but I also expect the answer will be that the 2008R2 database is running an earlier compatibility level and is not compatible with 2016 without an intermediate upgrade.

Comment: It's set to compatibility level 100 on the principal, so it falls within the 2008 range.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also occur in a scenario that is unrelated to mirroring.

If a database was previously attached to the newer SQL Server and you stop the service and copy the MDF/LDF from another server with an older version of SQL Server, you may get this error message when you restart the SQL Server service (because SQL Server expects to find a database with the current version, based on the information found in master).

The solution is to detach the database before copying a MDF with a newer version. However, if you try to detach it now, it will say that the database is suspect and cannot be detached. To overcome this error message, you can put the database in EMERGENCY mode and then detach it.

When you will attach an MDF with an older version, SQL Server will upgrade it to the current version automatically.